# "Cannot call method 'get' of undefined" in Chrome Extension popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on my Chrome Extension, I want my popup.js can get specific URL's cookies.
Here's my code in popup.js:

```
chrome.cookies.get({
        url: "http://live.gnbox.net",
        name: "foluser"
    }, function(cookie) {
        if (cookie) {
            alert('T');
        } else {
            alert('F');
        }
    }
);
```

The problem is,alert doesn't show up,and the console shows that "Cannot call method 'get' of undefined"
according to the [Chrome API page](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies.html),you  need to add "cookies" to permission in manifest.json,I do it like this:

```
"permissions": [ "cookies", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "notifications" ,"http://*.gnbox.net/" , "http://*.gnbox.net/","http://live.gnbox.net/"],
```

It still doesn't work, should I miss anything like library? or I have wrong code?

Comment: Which console do you see this error (popup or background)?
Such code worked for me. Maybe you added cookie permissions to manifest but did not reload the extension? Also you don't need to list specifics sites in permissions section of manifest because you use wildcards already

Comment: Are you attempting to run your code in a background or content script? My guess is that you are attempting to run it in your content script- see the related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23038032/why-is-chrome-cookies-undefined-in-a-content-script.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one, but this pulled up when I was searching for my own solution.  I had the same trouble when testing a chrome extension I was building.  If you make a change to the manifest (i.e. add cookies to your permissions) you need to uninstall your unpacked extension from chrome and reinstall it for the changes to the manifest to update.  Also remember to work with cookies in the background script, they are not accessible in the foreground script.