# Gmail Chrome Extension "chrome.extension" undefined

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a content script running inside the Gmail UI and I am injecting some new HTML at different points.  This is all working, but to keep the code clean I wanted to insert pre-defined HTML markup into certain parts of the page in a single function call.

This all seems feasible using chrome.extension.getURL(), but when I was testing this, it looks like chrome.extension is undefined! I was unable to find anywhere in the documentation that says this shouldn't be defined and several places where it says it should.

I am using chrome Version 39.0.2171.95 (64-bit)

Here is what the chrome object looks like in the javascript console:

[image: chrome object]

First off, anyone know why chrome.extension might be undefined? Secondly, is there another (perhaps better) way to do this? I'd rather not just programmatically inject a large amount HTML into the page in code using jQuery, etc. in the content script, but can resort to this if there is no other way.

Comment: Did you try to actually execute `chrome.extension.getURL()` in your code as opposed to testing the console? Or is your question specifically about the console?

Comment: I did - chrome.extension.getURL() gives this:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getURL' of undefined

Comment: In your content script code? Or are you injecting some other code from the content script?

Comment: This is called inside my content script JS

Comment: I don't think that's true. Anyway, writing an answer explaining it.

Comment: You are correct - I assumed (incorrectly) that since I injected another script from within a script defined in the manifest under "content scripts" that it is also a "content script" and would have the same properties in the chrome object. I appreciate the heads up!

Comment: Aha. Well, I mention this situation (commonly called "page-level script") in my answer. I tried to make it as extensive as possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're testing this in the console, you must be aware of the concept of the [Isolated World](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment). When you add a content script, it has a separate JavaScript context for itself that is isolated from the page.

At the top of the Console tab of Dev Tools, you'll see `<top frame>` in a dropdown. This is a dropdown that selects JS context it is executing in. It will list frames inside the document and all extensions that have content scripts injected.

The `chrome` object you show in the screenshot corresponds to what the webpage normally sees. If you switch context, you'll see a different picture:

[image: Switching context]

In any case, if you are really executing `chrome.extension.getURL()` in the content script - it will be well defined.

---

Now, if you injected a `<script>` tag in the page and tried it in that code - it would fail again, since the code will be in the page context. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27207129/934239) for this situation.

Finally, **most** of the Chrome API will not be exposed to content scripts for security reasons. If [an API is undefined when it shouldn't be](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23038032/934239), you may need a background page to do the job for you.