# console.log() not working when I load my chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am following the basics of creating a chrome extension 
      https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted
I placed a console.log() statement but it won't show up , should I be using some other API to log stuff on console?

Answer (score 7):

No, you should be *looking in the right place*.

- A [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) or [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)'s console and Dev Tools are accessible through the extension list in Developer mode - there [will be a link under the extension listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension).

  Extra note: event page's unload will lose the logs for it.
- A [popup page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction)'s console and Dev Tools are [accessible through right-clicking the action's button](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging) and selecting "Inspect popup".
- A [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)'s console and Dev Tools are accessible through the normal Dev Tools for the page that the content script executes in.

  Extra note: since a content script [executes in a different context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), you need to [select that context above the console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28216244/934239) if you want to run commands in it, as opposed to the page itself.