# How to Log to Console from Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Given a Chrome extension that sets up a `browser_action` based on a `default_icon` click, how can that extension print to the console? For example, say my `manifest.json` includes this:

```
{
  "name": "Testing",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "testing.html",
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

and my `testing.html` loads a `<script>` with some Javascript:

```
console.log("WHY DON'T I SEE THIS??");
```

Why doesn't this print anything to the console? And how might I go about getting something printed to the console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [console.log() not working when I load my chrome extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107503/console-log-not-working-when-i-load-my-chrome-extension)

Comment: Silly question, but did you actually click at the browser action button? Also, don't forget that the popup window runs in a separate context and it has a separate console. Right click on browser action button and click `Inspect popup`.

Comment: @Transcendental Thank you very much, that is exactly what I needed. I knew it was a separate console, but I couldn't figure out how to open it.