# chrome.storage not working as expected

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-storage

I am trying to save a list of dictionary objects in the chrome storage. But the following code seems to not work as expected.

When the extension loads for the first time and there is no `goal` object in the storage, `runtime.lasterror` object should be set and the code in that part should get executed. But it isn't.

When I uncomment the `chrome.storage.sync.set` line and save the object and the next time I call the function expecting it to save a list, it doesn't. It does not give any of the alert boxes.

```
function isPgUrl(pg_url,gl_name) {
  if(pg_url && gl_name) {

    dic_url={
      "name":gl_name,
      "pg_url":pg_url
    }

    //chrome.storage.sync.set({"goal":[dic_url]});

    chrome.storage.sync.get(["goal"], function(data) {
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        chrome.storage.sync.set({"goal":[dic_url]},function() {
          alert("blah");
        });
        alert("here");
        return;
      }
      var list=data.goal;
      list.append(dic_url);
      alert(list);
      chrome.storage.sync.set({"goal":list},function() {
        alert("lalala");
        return;
      });     
    });
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You'll never get `chrome.runtime.lastError` set for missing data. It's not an exception - you just get `undefined` value. So your check should be:

   ```
   if(!data.goal) { ... }
   ```

   or

   ```
   if(typeof data.goal === "undefined") { ... }
   ```
2. If you uncomment that line, you need to be aware that `chrome.storage` is asynchronous: the data is not in storage until the callback of `.set()`. So your `.get()` that is executed immediately after calling `.set()` may get a snapshot of the older view of the storage - making your code fail at `list.append(dic_url);`

   Not that `Array.prototype.append` exists in the first place. You should be using `.push()`.
3. Chrome Storage has a more efficient way of setting a default-if-not-in-storage value, by using an Object as a query:

   ```
   chrome.storage.sync.get({key: "defaultValue"}, function(data) {
     // data.key will be the stored value, or "defaultValue" if not in storage
   });
   ```

So, if I understand the purpose of your code correctly (append `dic_url` to `goal` in storage), this will do it:

```
// Makes more sense to default to empty list
chrome.storage.sync.get({goal: []}, function(data) {
  var list = data.goal;
  list.push(dic_url);
  chrome.storage.sync.set({goal: list}, function() {
    // Stoarge updated, dic_url appended to goal
  });
  // Storage is not yet updated - set() is async
});
// Storage is not yet updated - get()/set() are async
```

Comment: As an aside, don't use `alert()` for debugging - use `console.log()` and look [in the correct console](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36107503/934239).

Comment: thanks for the tip @Xan. I am trying the code given by you. Ill let you know asap.

Comment: Be aware I made a typo I just fixed - didn't add a `data` parameter to callback of `get()`

Comment: I tried your code @Xan with the default empty list. But it is still not working. First time the object is not being appended(on first run of execution). And when i append it by un-commenting the line and try executing your code by commenting it again, it is still not appending it.

Comment: Indeed. Because I trusted you that `append()` is an actual function. It isn't - it should be `push()`.

Comment: omg!! this was really really stupid!! thanks a lot @Xan. You were of great help. Everything works well now :)