# Active functions not printing in the console when it is converted in the form of chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have written a javascript code to print the active function calls of a webpage. When I paste the code in the console I can see the active functions in the console and the problem is with the extension. I converted the javascript code to google chrome extension and it is not working. I am new to extension creation.

Plugin Code:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "My Chrome Extension",
  "icons": {
  },

  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js"
    ]
  },

  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "My test Environment"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "background",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ]
}
```

js/background.js

```
function tracecalls(par) {
    for (var name in window) {
        if (typeof window[name] === 'function') {

            window[name] = (function (fname, f) {
                return function () {
                    par(fname);

                    return f.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            }(name, window[name]));
        }
    }
}
tracecalls(function (fname) {
    console.log("Function Name : " + fname);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background script runs in a separate page; even if the code did output something you're probably [looking in the wrong console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10257301/where-to-read-console-messages-from-background-js-in-a-chrome-extension).

Take time to read through [Architecture Overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch). If you want to interact with an existing tab, you need a [Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

But even if you set up a content script with this code, you won't see anything. Why? Because content script code and page code are [cleanly separated](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment) (and `window` object is not shared).

To interact with page code, another step, [page-level injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script), is required. If you do that, it should not be different from running the snippet in the console (that, by default, executes code you enter [in page's context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197570/cant-use-injected-jquery/28216244#28216244)).

Comment: I got it.. I injected the script in every page we open in the browser and the problem solved. Thanks for the suggestions.