# How to use external ajax response in Chrome Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I have a existing file ajax,js in my website that makes an ajax request and creates a global JSON object, searchResult using that response. Now I am creating a Chrome plugin, that requires this JSON Object inside it. I have a content script for the plugin viz. plugin.js and I want to include the object inside plugin.js file.

When I try to log window.searchResult from within plugin.js, it shows as undefined.

but when I use browser console, it shows the value as expected.

Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Chrome content scripts and the page's own scripts live in [isolated worlds](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment).

> Content scripts execute in a special environment called an isolated world. They have access to the DOM of the page they are injected into, **but not to any JavaScript variables or functions created by the page**.

Your code works in the console, since you execute it by default in the page's context. To see what the extension sees, you need to [switch it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913209/934239).

### Solution 1a

First, the generic solution (works even if you don't control the webpage)

There is a way around this, by injecting some code directly into the page's "world" (or properly called, context).

After [injecting the code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script), your page-level script needs to communicate with the content script to pass the data. It's [possible with custom DOM events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26740141/934239) (as, as you remember, DOM is shared). The page-level script sends an event with the data in the event's details.

Alternatively, you can just attach the data to some DOM node, say, an invisible `<div>`.

### Solution 1b

Since you said it's your page, you can skip the inject-into-the-page step and have a listener ready in the page's own code.

The content script sends a custom event to request the data, and the page answers passes the data back as described in 1a.

### Solution 2

In theory, you don't even need a content script.

You can use the [`"externally_connectable"` mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26095346/934239) to speak with the page directly.

Note though that the page has to initiate the conversation.