# Unable to call chrome api from script inside HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am new to Javascript as well as Chrome extension development. I was trying to open a tab when the user clicks on the extension button. This is how my `popup.html` looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title> Qoogle Homepage</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
var newURL = chrome.extension.getURL('qoogle.html');
chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
</script>
</head>
</html>
```

I have declared the `tabs` permission in my `manifest.json` and `qoogle.html` lays in the same directory. But when I click on the extension, nothing happens.

Now, I tried to include `<script src="popup.js"></script>` line into my `popup.html` and then wrote

```
var newURL = chrome.extension.getURL('qoogle.html');
chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
```

inside the popup.js file. This works fine.

I don't want too many files in my folder. What could be the reason my script does not get executed from the HTML and works fine when added separately as a JS file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the Docs:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed

Check out this answer as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27913209/3052648