# Chrome extension get JavaScript page variable

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, popup.js

I have [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) which loads a script like

```
<script src="external-url.js" async deferer></script>
```

This script has

```
var nameVariable = true;
```

How could I get the value (if it exists) in a popup.js of chrome extension?

Comment: Something like [Access global js variables from js injected by a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870005) - the second code snippet is what you put in the popup script.

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you but I don't understand that. with these code obtain errors and I don't know how to use it

Comment: Well, I can't help you without knowing what are the errors. See also the [extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).