# Why can I not access objects on a website in content scripts?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, content-script

I am working on a extension for Google Chrome, it will provide a refined experience when working with [Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/remix/hello-express). [Glitch](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/remix/hello-express) has a object that I am able to access from the Developer Tools console called `application`, when I try to access it from the content script I get a element with an id of `application` instead of the JavaScript object that the console gives me. I am using this for my content script.

```
console.log(window.application);
```

Inside the console I just type the following (and it works).

```
application
```

I have two videos below that will show off my issue, the first one shows my ability to access `application` from the console, and my second one shows my code and the issue.

[image: example 1]

[image: example 2]

Comment: Maybe is related to this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869780/access-global-js-variables-from-js-injected-by-a-chrome-extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that you cannot access the `window` object at all, but their are some solutions located here.

> [Access global js variables from js injected by a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869780/access-global-js-variables-from-js-injected-by-a-chrome-extension)
>   Located by @romellem