# Reading JSON that is written outside of a content script file Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to read a JSON object located in another js file using a chrome extension content script.

I tried listening for the page loading, and even used timeouts but it didn't work.

Is it possible to somehow access that json file? I am able to get it using the console, but not when using the content script js.

MCVE:

There is one file that is loaded by the website. Let's call it "loader" for now.

Loader defines a JSON object called "Derulo" and it contains this information {"Artist":false}. I am creating a Chrome extension that wants to use content script in order to take the "Derulo" JSON object that the website defined.

Comment: Depends. Add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) into the question.

Comment: done...........

Comment: That's not an MCVE but maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870005) will help.