# Wait for inject.js to execute completely before continuing in popup.js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with my chrome extension, the extension reads an object from the page and displays its contents in popup.js.

To read the object, popup executes injects.js which in turn injects script.js.

So what happens is, when inject.js  completes execution the popup.js callback is called and `renderData(mydata)`
is executed. I don't want this to happen until script.js is executed completely

**Popup.js**

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "inject.js" }, function() {
  renderData(mydata);
});
```

**inject.js**

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("script.js");
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(s);
```

**script.js**

```
 var data = {
    type: "FROM_PAGE",
    text: JSON.stringify(WIO.sessionInfo.context)
  };
  window.postMessage(data, "*");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that executeScript returns the last synchronously evaluated expression as the callback's parameter but a `script` with `src` runs asynchronously. BTW you forgot to specify the parameter.

Use `textContent` with literal code to run the script synchronously and send a DOM message, which is also synchronous, then leave the result in the last expression:

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "inject.js" }, ([mydata]) => {
  renderData(mydata);
});
```

inject.js

```
var data;
var eventId = 'event' + Math.random();
document.addEventListener(eventId, e => {
  data = JSON.parse(e.detail);
}, {once: true});

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.textContent = `(${eventId => {
  var data = JSON.stringify(WIO.sessionInfo.context);
  document.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(eventId, {detail: data}));
}})('${eventId}')`;
document.documentElement.appendChild(script);
script.remove();

data;
```

Alternatively you can use [extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to send the data to the popup ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870005)).

Comment: Thank you @wOxxOm, the code run perfectly. However, i have a question. Why does the mydata object received in popup.js sorted in alphabetic order?

Comment: I don't know what you mean but I guess it's probably because of JSON.stringify+JSON.parse so try removing them both. Anyway, this is a separate issue so you should post another question if needed.