# Google Chrome extension - how to inject a content script?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Hi I am working on a Google Chrome extension for educational purposses. How I can load JavaScript script to have access to the page.

Here is my loader.js:

```
s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = chrome.extension.getURL("src/content_script.js");

s.onload = function(){
   this.remove();
}

document.head.appendChild(s);
```

and here is my content_script.js:

```
var formats = ytplayer.config.args.raw_player_response.streamingData.formats;
console.log("YT extension loaded!");
```

Problem is that I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: chrome.extension.getURL is not a function
> at loader.js:2:26

Can someone give me suggestions on what the problem might be?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's chrome.runtime.getURL. See also [an alternative way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870005).

Comment: Use `chrome.runtime.getURL`

Comment: `chrome.extension.getURL` is deprecated, as mentioned above use `chrome.runtime.getURL`

Comment: Hi, the chrome.extension.getURL seems to work so if someone actualy answer the question via the answer option will be nice. If you do please provide more info on where it is stated that crhome.extension.getURL is depricated.

Comment: Firstly, it is 100% chrome.runtime.getURL() in manifest v3. Secondly, why are you injecting the content script into the page? Does it need to run in page context? You need to share your manifest because the script alone is not sufficient to determine the problem.

Answer (score 0):

According to [official Chrome documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/extension/#method-getURL), the `chrome.extension.getUrl` method has been deprecated as of Chrome 58. Moving forward, use the `chrome.runtime.getUrl` method to achieve the same results.

`chrome.extension.getUrl` may still work, however when migrating to Manifest V3 chrome will not allow you to load an extension in the browser using the deprecated `extension` implementation.