# `chrome.scripting` undefined with Manifest v3

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm building a cross-browser extension and when I tried to migrate the extension from Firefox (manifest v2) to Chrome (manifest v3), everything seems to broke.

In my extension I need to get a variable injected by the webpage in JavaScript. My original solution was to directly inject a `<script />` tag with my js code inside and it worked fine in Firefox. But in Chrome maybe because of this site's strict CSP policy, I can no longer inject scripts.

And I found [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870005/13266491) about how to fetch page variables in content script. But while trying this solution I encountered another error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'executeScript')
```

The code I used was directly copied from the answer:

```js
export const getPageVar = async (name: string, tabId?: number) => {
  const [{ result }] = await browser.scripting.executeScript({
    func: (name) => console.log(name),
    args: [name],
    target: {
      tabId:
        tabId ??
        (
          await browser.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true })
        )[0].id,
    },
  });
  return result;
};
```

And I called it like:

```js
// ...
const result = await getPageVar("_feInstance");
```

Here is my `manifest.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "Luogu Improved",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Improve Luogu to a new level.",
  "homepage_url": "https://github.com/samzhangjy/luogu-improved",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "icons": {
    "192": "../../../icons/icon-192.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "scripting",
    "declarativeContent"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "https://www.luogu.com.cn/*"
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://www.luogu.com.cn/*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "../src/plugins.ts"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "../src/index.ts",
    "type": "module"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": "../../../icons/icon-32.png",
    "default_title": "Luogu Improved",
    "default_popup": "../../lim-launch-page/dist/index.html"
  }
}
```

And btw, I have another error other than the above one but the rest of the code seemed to be working fine even with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'onActivated')
```

And my code is something like:

```js
browser.tabs.onActivated.addListener(() => registerPlugins(defaultPlugins));
browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(() => registerPlugins(defaultPlugins));
browser.tabs.onHighlighted.addListener(() => registerPlugins(defaultPlugins));
```

I've been struggling with this for two days and didn't have a clue... Thanks in advance!!

**EDIT**: I'm using [`webextension-polyfill`](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill) in my code. I import it like:

```js
import * as browser from "webextension-polyfill";
```

Comment: The only explanations are: 1) you didn't reload the extension after editing manifest.json, 2) you're running this code in the wrong context e.g. inside a content script or inside a web page like http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1. Maybe your worker module gets included incorrectly somewhere else. BTW there should be no need for a polyfill in MV3.