# Chrome extension Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'appendChild')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

### Manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "Getting Started Example",
  "description": "Build an Extension!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "32": "icons/32x32.png"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*"],
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "scripting",
    "tabs",
    "notifications",
    "activeTab",
    "webRequest"
  ],
  "host_permissions": ["*://*/*", "https://*/*"],
  "web_accessible_resources": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*/*", "http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "resources": ["web.js"]
    }
  ],
  "icons": {
    "32": "/icons/32x32.png"
  }
}
```

### content-script.js

```js
console.log("I am content script");
function injectScript() {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = chrome.runtime.getURL("scripts/web.js");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  console.log("Inserting Script", document);
  document.head.appendChild(script);
}
injectScript();
```

### web.js

```js
console.log("I am web.js");

setInterval(() => {
  console.log(window.test, "Test in setInterval");
}, 1000);

console.log(window.test, "Logging test from web.js");

// document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Upon refreshing the page I am getting the following error
[image]

Not able to get what could be the issue, can someone guide me?
Thank You!

Comment: Why are you injecting a file into the page?

Comment: Maybe answer here will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/use-a-content-script-to-access-the-page-context-variables-and-functions

Comment: I want to read and write into `window` object in scope of the page

Comment: The above question is too old, we are using manifesr V3.

Comment: A lot of things has been removed in V3 which was in V2

Comment: I see V3 there in the answers, unless I am mistaken.

Comment: Looking for someone who has faced the similar issue in V3, still will look into the answer

Comment: Replace `head` with `documentElement`. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870005/).

Comment: @wOxxOm `documentElement` worked, thanks for sharing this