# Chrome extension, send message from injected code (world 'MAIN') to background

Tags: sendmessage, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a script that injects a js file in each tab via

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({, world: 'MAIN'})
```

I do that as i want to access variables of the loaded pages.

In this injected code i want to send a message to background via

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage()
```

though in the page console i get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sendMessage')
```

manifest.json (shrinked)

```
{
   "manifest_version": 3,
   "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js",
      "type": "module"
   },
   "permissions": [
      "scripting"
   ]

}
```

background.js

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
   target: {tabId: tabId},
   files: [
      './js/asdf.js'
   ],
   world: 'MAIN'
}).then()
```

./js/asdf.js

```
console.log("asdfasdf"); # is printed
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({action: '...'}).then()
```

As soon as i do not run the script with world 'MAIN' i can access the method 'sendMessage'.

How can i send infos from a script injected into world 'MAIN' to the background? :)

Comment: No need for sendMessage, there's a much simpler method: use a function in executeScript: [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46870005). It can be an `async` function that returns a Promise.

Comment: thx for your response, when i use the args attribute it seems i cannot use any files anymore - ```Uncaught (in promise) Error: 'args' may not be used with file injections.``` - though i have a few classes that i need to use :( - is there any other option?

Comment: `args` is not necessary. The important part is to end the executed code with an expression e.g. `foo()` at the end of your script and it will be transferred back into executeScript.

Comment: thx again for your response, i think i lack knowlegde to understand your response  - it would help to push data to the script and receive data from it?

Comment: i came across this [postMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#host-page-communication) in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/access-variables-and-functions-defined-in-page-context-using-a-content-script/9517879#comment94436100_19312198) - will try that out

Answer (score 1):

For my scenario the following worked:

content script (world: isolated)

```
window.addEventListener("load", async function () {
    //get state from background
    const state = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({});


    ....
    //send state to page
    window.postMessage();
});

//receive response from page
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    //send info to background
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage();
}, false);
```

background.js (inject code into page)

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tabId},
        files: [
            'classes.js',
            '.main.js',
        ],
        world: 'MAIN',
    }).then();
```

classes.js

```
//receive info from content script   
window.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
   //do something based on received state 
}, false);

//post something back to content script
window.postMessage();
```

process:

- get state from background by sendMessage in content script
- based on state info content script sends postMessage to page
- postMessage triggers process in page (injected code)
- code does something and sends postMessage to content script
- content script had listened for postMessage and forwards info to background by sendMessage