# How can we communicate between background and a content script running in world MAIN

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions, web-extension

I have a content script (running in world MAIN) that is listening to changes in `console.log` and it should send a message to `background.ts` when a `console.log` happens.

`manifest.json`

```json
{
"content_scripts": [
    {
      "world": "MAIN",
      "js": ["src/contentScripts/registerConsoleLogs.ts"],
      "matches": [
          "http://*/*",
          "https://*/*"
      ],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
}
```

`registerConsoleLogs.ts`

```js
console.stdlog = console.log.bind(console)

console.log = function () {
  console.stdlog.apply(console, arguments)

  const payload = {
    name: 'registerLog',
    payload: { severity: 'warning', log: arguments }
  }
}

export default {}
```

`background.ts`

```js
browser.runtime.onMessage.addListener((request, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (request.name === 'registerLog') {
    console.log('log received: ')
    console.log(request.payload)
  }
})
```

My doubt is: how can I send a message from `registerConsoLogs.ts` to `background.ts`?

The examples ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255573/chrome-extension-send-message-from-injected-code-world-main-to-background), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/access-variables-and-functions-defined-in-page-context-using-a-content-script?noredirect=1&lq=1)) do not use the `world: "MAIN"`. I'm fairly new to developing web extension and would love some guidance on how to pass the messages from content script with `world: "MAIN"` to `background`

Comment: A `MAIN` world script is just a web page script, it has no access to any of the extension's API by default, so you'll need to use CustomEvent messaging with a second content script without `world`, which will forward the message into the extension. There should be examples for ManifestV2 (basically same as MV3) around for using messaging e.g. [Can a site invoke a browser extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10527809) (note that your MAIN world script is the *"injected script"* in MV2).