Chrome extensions exchange message between extension script (from popup) and content script (not isolated)
I'm writing Chrome Extension where my extension script needs some data for current tab. I have content script which have access to DOM and window object. It is run with "world" "MAIN" property, non isolated, because I want access to actual window object with augmented with specific data with third party script. I have following code:
Manifest.json:
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Plugin",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Plugin",
  "permissions": [
    "cookies",
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "scripting",
    "tabs"
  ]
  "host_permissions": [
    <list of urls>
  ],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "world": "MAIN",
      "js": ["content.js"],
      "matches": [
        <list of urls>
      ]
    }
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon_16x16.png",
    "48": "icon_48x48.png",
    "128": "icon_128x128.png"
  }
}

content.js
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
    if (port.name === 'test') {
        port.postMessage({
            type: 'test',
            status: window.someCustomProperty,
        })
    }
});

And my script from popup.html
const port = chrome.tabs.connect(activeTabId, {name: 'test'});

port.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
  resolve(message.status);
  console.log('MESSAGE', message);
});

port.onDisconnect.addListener(() => {
  reject();
  console.log('DISCONNECTED');
});

Problem is that it isn't working. When I run my content.js script with "world": "MAIN" in manifest.json, chrome.runtime is undefined. When I run content.js script without "world": "MAIN", window.someCustomProperty is undefined, because it runs in isolation. I've read several resources about similiar problem on SO and web, but none solved this issue.

Please see this.

"I've read several resources about similiar problem on SO and web, but none solved this issue." - I'm afraid this information is not very helpful, because it doesn't tell us what you've already found. So at the risk of telling you something you already know: I searched Stack Overflow for "chrome world main", and the second result was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74255573/chrome-extension-send-message-from-injected-code-world-main-to-background

Your script is not a privileged script anymore, so you can use externally_connectable messaging for web pages, see the documentation. Note that the port can be opened by the script in the web page, not by the popup, but the popup can listen to messages on this port and thus receive commands.

@woxxom externally_connectable is the answer - thank you. Didn't noticed it in chrome docs, post answer if you want to.
