# Get js variable from page and pass its value to background.js

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There is a webpage that constantly (every 100oms) log out a variable called "t", which is a json type.
My goal is get the content of t variable in content.js (or some other injection method), pass it to background.js or popup.js and show up popup.html. it needs to run at same pace, like 1000ms as the t variable refresh every 1 second.

I am stucked at first step, i don't know how to get the variable in the main page.
i do found some post have similar topic like this one: [Access global js variables from js injected by a chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869780/access-global-js-variables-from-js-injected-by-a-chrome-extension), but i need more detailed implementation.

Comment: "There is a webpage" - What is the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of it.

[image]

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "permissions": [
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="div"></div>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```js
const getHoge = () => {
  return t;
}

const main = async () => {
  while (1) {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, (tabs) => {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tabs[0].id, },
        world: "MAIN",
        func: getHoge
      }, (result) => {
        document.getElementById("div").innerText = result[0].result;
      });
    });

    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 500));
  }
}

main();
```

[test web page](https://nory-soft.web.app/test/20230501.html)

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div id="div">
    </divz>
    <script>
      let t;
      let i = 0;
      let div = document.getElementById("div");

      const main = async () => {
        while (1) {
          t = JSON.stringify({ i: i });
          div.innerText = t;
          await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
          i++;
        }
      }

      main();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. It gives me error when i load to Chrome:
Error handling response: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
the line that heighted is
        document.getElementById("div").innerText = result[0].result;

Comment: Did you remove "<div id="div"></div>" from my popup.html?

Comment: thanks, it worked on your page, i was test on my other page which is slightly different.

Comment: You had a extra z in div box in HTML code, line 4: "</divz>".